# Update a DataTable in C# without using a loop?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

Let suppose there are three columns in my DataTable

1. code
2. name
3. color

If I know the code and name, how can I update the color of that specific row whose code and name match my criteria? I want to do this **without using Loops!**

Comment: Why in the world do you want to do this without using loops? *Somewhere*, a loop will be required. Even if you use LINQ, a loop is still performed internally.

Comment: Cody, the OP wants to update 1 row. A Dictionary wouldn't require a loop.

Comment: A table is not a dictionary

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
DataRow dr = datatable.AsEnumerable().Where(r => ((string)r["code"]).Equals(someCode) && ((string)r["name"]).Equals(someName)).First();
dr["color"] = someColor;
```

Of course I'm assuming all those criteria are strings. You should change the casts to the correct types.

Comment: Now i am getting error at Data.EnumerableRowCollection does not contain .First() Also we are just updating a row how will reflect these changes in DataTable.

Comment: Make sure you're `using System.Linq`, but `Where()` shouldn't be working either if that wasn't being referenced. By "reflect the changes" do you mean seeing them on the screen? You'll need to re-bind the DataTable to whatever you're using to display it.

Comment: This is fine, as far as it goes...however, if the user wants to update multiple rows...this won't work.

Answer (score 13):

```
// Use the Select method to find all rows matching the name and code.
DataRow[] rows = myDataTable.Select("name 'nameValue' AND code = 'codeValue');

for(int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i ++)
{
      rows[i]["color"] = colorValue;
}
```

Comment: How this updated row will be reflected back(Commited) to myDataTable

Comment: @Zain:This already does the update. Use the Select method of the DataTable to locate a specific row and assign new values to the desired columns. That's it.

Comment: should be DataRow[] rows = myDataTable.Select("name = 'nameValue' AND code = 'codeValue')

Answer (score 5):

```
DataTable recTable = new DataTable();

// do stuff to populate table

recTable.Select(string.Format("[code] = '{0}' and [name] = '{1}'", someCode, someName)).ToList<DataRow>().ForEach(r => r["Color"] = colorValue);
```

Comment: This is still a loop

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ:

```
var dataRows = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(c => { c["color"] = c["Code"].ToString() == "1" ? "Red" : "White"; return c; });
dt = dataRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score -3):

You could do:

```
 foreach (DataRow row in datatable.Rows)
        {
            if(row["code"].ToString() == someCode && row["name"].ToString() == someName)

              {
                  row["color"] = someColor;
              }


        }
```

Comment: -1 -> The poster stated in his question to not use loops.  I understand this works but it already breaks the criteria of the question from the get go.

Comment: If the request criteria make no sense, a 'textbook' solution like this one by @Darren is much appreciated by other possible users. Any LINQ routine uses loops inside, and they are far less efficient than a simple for-loop.  +1 upvote .